# where is window.document.referrer coming from?

Tags: javascript

I have an application that uses window.document.referrer to fill some backbutton url.
I thought that window.document.referrer in JS was filled by the HTTP referer header, but when I change that header with a intercepting proxy like BURP the window.document.referrer is still the correct one.

So where is this value being set?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)?

Comment: @esko I did, and nowhere it tells where it comes from. Not even the link to the w3c specification.

Comment: The referrer header is sent from the browser to the server, therefore the client will know where it came from, just the server will not

Comment: @scagood — The question is very explicitly not about the referer HTTP header.

Comment: The documentation isn't clear about it. @scagood: I would indeed think that, but when I change the referer header it doesn't change the variable

Comment: @Wealot the W3C specification also says it's readonly.

Comment: @Quentin - What do you mean, he says that a proxy changed the http request referrer header? Then you effectively re-post my comment as an answer

Comment: @scagood google for Burp suite, it is an intercepting proxy that enables you to change HTTP requests before the browser sends them to the server. (similar to fiddler)

Comment: @Wealot - Exactly the HTTP request would be, `browser` -> `proxy` -> `server`. Then the response would be `server` -> `proxy` -> `browser`. You changed a `HTTP Request` header, not a `HTTP Response` header. Both Requests and Responses have headers. The Response (generally) does not contain a `Referrer` header. It's the browsers Request that sets both the `referrer header` and the `window.location.referer`

Comment: @scagood What I misunderstood was that the browser send the header separate from the window.location.referrer. But now I get it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is generated, internally, by the browser.

> when I change that header with a intercepting proxy like BURP the window.document.referrer is still the correct one

The referer header comes *from* the browser. Changing it after it left the browser but before it reached the server couldn't have any effect on what the browser thought it was sending.

Comment: why did you post this as community wiki? Not accusing, just curious.

Comment: OK, thanks that makes it clear. I really thought that when sending the header the browser would also think that it would be the header value, but it makes sense it ignores that.